# How to properly delete a cell in a tableview cell? using swipe touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i'm trying to delete a cell for my tableview array using the swipe event. I'm able to get the swipe event, the delete button show up but when i click on delete i get this error:

> -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17400f1b0 2017-10-16 13:14:02.957825
>   oFiOSstoryboard[487:70100] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSSingleObjectArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x17400f1b0'

Not sure how to fixed it here is the full code:

```
//
//  CameraViewController.m
//  oFiOSstoryboard
//
//  Created by Dorald on 24/05/15.
//
//

#import "CameraViewController.h"
#import "resultsDetailView.h"


@interface CameraViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *data;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeStamp;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *dirList;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *csvRow;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *dataArray;


- (IBAction)didTapDeleteBtn:(id)sender;


@end

                                 ////////////////////////csv readder
NSMutableArray *tableDataArray;

NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *direnum = [manager enumeratorAtPath:bundleRoot];
NSString *filename;
NSMutableArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *strPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"csv"];
NSString *strFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:strPath  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSMutableArray *timeStampb = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; ;
NSMutableArray *arrayToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; ;
NSMutableArray *filePathsArray ;
//NSMutableArray *dirList= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; ;
NSString *currentcsvfile;
NSString *csvfilenameSave;

@implementation CameraViewController



@synthesize data;


- (void)viewDidLoad  {
[super viewDidLoad];
  // ////lista de documentos

    self.data.scrollEnabled = YES;

    self.data.delegate = self;
    self.data.dataSource = self;


    //filePathsArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; ;


    self.data.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;


    self.dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSInteger count = 100;
    for (NSInteger i = count; i>=0; i--) {
        NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell %ld",i];
        [self.dataArray addObject:title];
    }
    NSMutableArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSMutableArray*   fileList = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
    //--- Listing file by name sort
    NSLog(@"\n File list %@",fileList);

    //---- Sorting files by extension
    NSMutableArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF EndsWith '.csv'"];
    filePathsArray =  [filePathsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSLog(@"\n\n Sorted files by extension %@",filePathsArray);



    self.dirList = filePathsArray;

    NSString *docPath =[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];

   if (!strFile) {
        NSLog(@"Error reading file.");
    }

    [timeStampb release];


      timeStampb = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[strFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\,"]];
        // this .csv file is seperated with new line character
        // if .csv is seperated by comma use "," instesd of "\n"
    for(NSString *countryname in timeStampb) {
        NSLog(@"%@", timeStampb);

    }


    }


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Delete csv files
//- (IBAction)delet:(id)sender {
//    NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
//    
//    NSString *filePath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"jorge.csv"];
//    NSError *error = nil;
//    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
//}




- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


# pragma – mark table view DataSource Methods
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.dirList count];

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";



    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier ];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed:(254.0/255.0) green:(251.0/255.0) blue:(248.0/255.0) alpha:1];
        UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];

        bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(253.0/255.0) green:(0.0/255.0) blue:(237.0/255.0) alpha:1];


        [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
        cell.backgroundColor = color;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [timeStampb objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.dirList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(0.0/255.0) green:(0.0/255.0) blue:(0.0/255.0) alpha:1];
    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:8.0];

    cell.detailTextLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(235.0/255.0) green:(120.0/255.0) blue:(33.0/255.0) alpha:1];



    return cell;


}



-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



    NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row);


        currentcsvfile = [self.dirList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ];;

    //////////////////////////////////////////text file


    csvfilenameSave = [NSString stringWithFormat:currentcsvfile];


    NSArray *paths3 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory3 = [paths3 objectAtIndex:0];

    //make a file name to write the data to using the documents directory:
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/currentcsvnamefile.txt",
                          documentsDirectory3];
    //create content - four lines of text
    NSString *content =csvfilenameSave;
    //save content to the documents directory
    [content writeToFile:fileName
              atomically:NO
                encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];

    [_dirList addObject:_dirList[indexPath.row]];


    NSLog(@"\n current csv csvfilenameSave % ",csvfilenameSave);



//[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailsegue" sender:self];

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Update the delete button's title based on how many items are selected.
    [_dirList removeObject:_dirList[indexPath.row]];



}


-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)data:(UITableView *)data editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ( editingStyle== UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [_dirList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.data deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [data setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    }
}

#pragma mark - UITableView Delegate Methods

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}


#pragma mark - Delete Button Action


#pragma mark – TableView delegate

- (void)dealloc {
    [_timeStamp release];

    [self.dirList release];
    self.data.delegate = nil;
    self.data.dataSource = nil;


    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: From the error it seems you are trying to remove an object from an immutable array, and immutable array's don't respond to mutation methods. You either assume an immutable array is a mutable one, or somehow during the controller lifecycle the array becomes immutable.

Comment: Specifically, `dirList`  is an immutable array. Objective C is not strongly types, so even though you have declared the variable as a mutant array pointer, it does not complain when you assign the immutable array returned by your filtering predicate and declaring the variable of a type does not magically change the type of the underlying object. You need to say `self.dirList = [filePathsArray mutableCopy]`

Comment: Thanks! that's working.